# Section titles without numbers in non-starred version

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, memoir

I am trying to format the section title in the `memoir` class, so there is no section numbers in it, and I don't want to use the `\section*`command because it makes it more cumbersome to make it show up in the table of contents and in the heading.

At the moment, the relevant part of my preamble looks like this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% CHAPTER FORMAT

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
    {\thechapter}
    {10pt}
    {\Huge}

% SECTION FORMAT

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}
\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}
    {0\parskip}
    {0\parskip}
    [0pt]

% SUBSECTION FORMAT

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\itshape\normalsize}
    {\thesubsection}
    {}
    {}
\titlespacing{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {0\parskip}
    {-1\parskip}
    [0pt]
```

Even though I have set the `secnumdepth`to `0`, the numbering in the section title is still there.

Here is exactly what I want:

- Chapters, Sections and Subsections in TOC
- Numbered Chapters (Both in text and in TOC)
- Unnumbered Sections and Subsections (both in text and TOC), but without using `\section*`

My only problem is that I can't seem to get rid of the section numbering.

EDIT:

As requested, here comes a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% LANGUAGE/HYPHENATION

\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}

% INDENTS AND MORE

\setlength{\baselineskip}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} % Skip size after paragraph
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % Indent size
\usepackage{indentfirst} % 

% HEADER / PAGE STYLE

\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

\copypagestyle{thesis}{myheadings}
\makerunningwidth{thesis}{\headwidth}
\makeheadrule{thesis}{\headwidth}{0.2pt}
\makeheadposition{thesis}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}

\makepsmarks{thesis}{%
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{} 
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

\makeevenhead{thesis}%
    {\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{thesis}%
    {\sffamily\bfseries\small\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}

\pagestyle{thesis}

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty} % empty page style

% FORMAT TOC + LOF + LOT

\renewcommand\printtoctitle{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\printloftitle{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\printlottitle{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}

% FONTS

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}

% FORMAT CHAP, SEC, SUBSEC
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% CHAPTER FORMAT

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
    {\thechapter}
    {1em}
    {\Huge}

% SECTION FORMAT

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}
\titlespacing{\section}
    {0pt}
    {0\parskip}
    {0\parskip}
    [0pt]

% SUBSECTION FORMAT

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\itshape\normalsize}
    {\thesubsection}
    {}
    {} % Intet linieskift efter subsection 
\titlespacing{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {0\parskip}
    {-1\parskip}
    [0pt]

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\paragraph*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd just stop using `titlesec` and use `\setsecnumdepth{chapter}\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}`, that is enough. I do not know what `titlesec` *messes* up. And BTW, please please always post *full* minimal examples, that we can copy and poste without having to add or alter them

Comment: What do you use for formatting the chapter title, section title etc. then?

Comment: Memoirs own interface of couse

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked with the `\setsecnumdepth{chapter}\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}` command instead of the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`--even with the titlesec package.

Comment: Probably because of mainmatter it resets to maxsecnumdepth, so if you do not have it It fails

Comment: @daleif Do you want to answer that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not much reason to use titlesec here. Just use memoirs own interface to format the though.

But, when you want to use frontmatter and mainmatter plus want to generally change the secnumdepth, remember to use

```
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}
```

The maxsecnumdepth (bad name) is what the secnumdepth is reset to at the start of mainmatter